# Meaning of "Why do narcissists flaunt their new supply?"

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

Could someone explain the meaning of this senetence to me?

I found this senetence **"Why do narcissists flaunt their new supply?"** when trying to learn the word **narcissist**. I am not able to understand the sentence.

I tried and understood the following words:

Narcissist = it’s a disorder. People with this has excessive self interest and do not consider others.

Flaunt = trying to impress others (or) trying to get admiration.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C8WSqszTPlA

Comment: It's esoteric mumbo-jumbo related to how a narcissist flaunts his or her new partner to make the old partner feel bad.  Rubbing it in their face, so to speak.  The word supply seems to indicate that the partner is a source of supply for all the attention and pampering the narcissist requires.

Comment: I think @BruceMurray has explained it well. I'm a native American English speaker for decades, and I had to google the phrase to even understand what it was about. The sentence doesn't stand alone, it is (evidently) used in the context of a narcissist who has broken up with a romantic partner and is now making a public show (i.e. 'flaunting') a new romantic partner; both the former and new romantic partners were (or are assumed to be) people who supplied the narcissist with the adulation the narcissist desires, therefore being a "supply" of it. Mumbo-jumbo indeed.

Comment: @rcook, Surely you mean: I've been a native American English speaker for decades....

Comment: @Lambie LOL -- of course I did... thanks for correcting that.